# How to import modules without requests?

Tags: python

need to be able to use networkx and matplotlib libraries on a PC that does not have them installed. I used requests, but as it turned out, it also needs to be installed. Is there any other way to implement this ?

```
import requests
requests.get('https://raw.github.com/networkx/networkx')
requests.get('https://raw.github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib')
```

ModuleNotFoundError: no module named requests

Comment: It might be a good idea to search for APIs. I think is the exact thing that you might want: calling remote functions without installing anything.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Use urllib instead of requests

```py
import urllib.request
request = urllib.request.Request("https://raw.github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib", method="GET")
with urllib.request.urlopen(request) as response:
    # code
```

Also I don't think you can import modules like that, You have an internet connection so just use pip to install the modules you need

Comment: Thanks for the reply). The problem is that the recipient of the file will not install anything, he just needs code using these modules

Comment: Use an api that does the things you want instead